# How can i predict the future of this data

Tags: python, prediction

I got 180 days of json data for buying and selling items in a game, the data i got is: timestamp, buy_price, sell_price, buy_quantity and sell_quantity.
I want to predict the future price of this item based on previous data, I found a lot of machine learning data on google but i'm curious what you guys would recommend me using? and how should I do this?

Comment: use time series ...

Comment: What @cph_sto mentioned but look for time series forecasting. That is probably what you are looking for. There is actually a lot of information about it just need to google it.

Comment: Yep, we'll just divulge this info on SO. "Predicting" the market is a rite of passage into machine learning. It will fail (If you're an outsider). They call it "dumb money" for a reason.

Comment: Have a look at autorregressive models (AR) and, on the same line (even though you do not have much data) RNNs (Recurrent Neural Networks), particularly LSTMs (Long Short-Term Memory models).

Comment: R has good packages to implement all what David has mentioned ... use that

Comment: It won't work. If it did, we'd all be loaded.

Answer (score 2):

This is a regression task. You can use simple regression model (this is an example of predicting house prices in Boston):

```
from sklearn import linear_model
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets ## imports datasets from scikit-learn
data = datasets.load_boston() ## loads Boston dataset from datasets 

# define the data/predictors as the pre-set feature names  
df = pd.DataFrame(data.data, columns=data.feature_names)

# Put the target (housing value -- MEDV) in another DataFrame
target = pd.DataFrame(data.target, columns=["MEDV"])

X = df
y = target['MEDV']

lm = linear_model.LinearRegression()
model = lm.fit(X,y)

predictions = lm.predict(X)
print(predictions)[0:5]
```

You can read more about it here https://towardsdatascience.com/simple-and-multiple-linear-regression-in-python-c928425168f9

Better use Xgboost model, or neural networks (but neural networks need to customize and a lot of data to avoid overfitting, whereas xgboost you can use at once)

Example with xgboost:

```
import xgboost as xgb
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets ## imports datasets from scikit-learn
data = datasets.load_boston() ## loads Boston dataset from datasets 

# define the data/predictors as the pre-set feature names  
df = pd.DataFrame(data.data, columns=data.feature_names)

# Put the target (housing value -- MEDV) in another DataFrame
target = pd.DataFrame(data.target, columns=["MEDV"])

X = df
y = target['MEDV']

lm = xgb.XGBRegressor()
model = lm.fit(X,y)

predictions = lm.predict(X)
print(predictions)[0:5]
```